# What is the use of Order And Export tab in Java Build Path

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, buildpath, java

What is the use of **Order And Export** tab in Java Build Path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13942953/632951

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It allows you to do two things:

- Determine in which order projects and libraries appear in the classpath. If there are any duplicate classes, this determines which version is loaded
- Determine which projects and libraries will be exported and thus available in other projects that depend on this one.

Comment: In Eclipse, I have a project TEST which is dependent on Project TEST2 and an externat jar external.jar. While creating jar for TEST Project with Order and Export option checked , created jar is not including TEST2.jar or external.jar.. So how I can do this to run the TEST.jar idependently ?

Comment: @Dhrubo: JARs cannot include other JARs. I think you can configure the JAR builder of eclipse to include all the *classes*, but the normal way to do it is to have several JARs and include them all in the classpath when running the application.

Comment: what difference 'checking and unchecking' a particular entry makes?

Comment: @Darpan: only checked ones are visible to dependent projects.

Comment: blue dot before library name ?

Comment: @TusharPandey: I think that happens only for the project's own source folders, which are always exported.

Answer (score 5):

Got some hint here for you:

**Order and Export.** Order in which projects and libraries appear in the build path and the default runtime classpath; e.g., use classes from a workspace project before using the same classes from an archive library.

Found it on [informit.com](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=367962)

Comment: Specifically, the classes higher in the list will take precedence over the classes lower in the list.