# Eclipse for android: Issues with R

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to do a location app and am in the trouble shooting phase right now.  I am down to my last two problems and they both relate to R. blah blah.  It says main is either not a field or cannot be resolved and the same message but with mapview instead of main.  Below are my imports and the lines of code where the issue is.

Code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

Imports:

```
    import android.R;
    import android.R.layout;
    import android.R.id;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

I've tried everything.  I know people keep saying to take out android.R but that is where R.layout and R.id are found in the jar files.  I have right clicked the folder and validated the code.  I have gone to Project/Clean and done that.  No luck.  Please help?  And this is my first post so I'm sorry if its formatted wrong.  I thank you in advance for any help you give me.
Here is my main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Waiting for location..."
        android:id="@+id/lblLocationInfo"
    />
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0vFrUOhHMkbahT9zXqiz_DuNVWfPqlEyqcO8ftg"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your main.xml? Also have you added this in your Manifest application tag: `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`

Comment: I have and i will add the main.xml now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless you are using resources from android you shouldn't need the lines

```
import android.R; 
import android.R.Id;
import android.R.layout;
```

**Remove those lines**

R is resolving to androids R and not `com.yourpackage.yourproject.R`.

Remove the import if it's not needed. If it is your need to be explicit in your code. ex.

```
ImageView.setDrawable(android.R.ic_menu_search); //uses an android resource

findViewById(R.id.mapView); //uses your resource file

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // must have an activity_main.xml file in YourProject/res/layout
```

**Edit:**

changes to your code below:

```
//import android.R;
//import android.R.layout;    //comment or delete these lines
//import android.R.id;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  //changed main to activity_main
mapview = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

**Edit 2**

At the very top of your MainActivity.java it should have a line that starts with `package` what does the rest of that line say?

In your AndroidManifest.xml there is also an entry for package what does it say?

Comment: I'm new to programming...that made almost no sense.  Can you explain what that means?

Comment: No problem I updated the answer... Android has it own resources. If you start by removing the 3 lines I suggested and do a clean and build and see where that gets you.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense.  I removed those lines but I still have those two errors.

Comment: In your project under res/layout is there a main.xml file?

Comment: Yes there is.  activity_main.xml

Comment: Then your code should read `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` That should resolve one of the issues.

Comment: So should I just copy/paste those 3 lines in that you gave me?

Comment: Tucker, it is clear you don't know what you're doing. I suggest you read more about R. It's the Resources file that is auto generated. It assigns integer values to pictures, sound files, etc so you can call it in your application. What you're doing is you are importing android.R. You're supposed to use your own R file located in `gen/R.java`. So remove the 3 `android.R` imports.

Comment: I know I don't know what I'm doing.  That's why I'm asking for help.  I got this far I just need help with 2 issues.  I realize that's what I'm doing.  I put those three in to see if being more specific about where I was importing them from would fix it.  It obviously didn't.  So I took them out.

Comment: It now says that R cannot be resolved to be a variable.  That did fix the other problem with mapview and main though.

Comment: Did you try clicking Project->Clean another though do you have any other errors in your layout or other files located in res directory?

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help.  You answered the question that I had posted with which has been plaguing me for about a week.  Thank you very much!

Comment: They both say the same thing.  I noticed and fixed it earlier.  They both say "com.example.googlemaps"

Comment: I found my problem!! To anyone else having this issue, go to the following site! http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the line:

```
import android.R;
```

And then do Build Clean, this can fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`R.java` it's a self generated file, you need to re-build it for it to get generated, ignore  the warnings and "Build Clean" your file

Answer (score 0):

This might also have to do with your project setup. What I typically do when I create a new project is setup 'Order and Export' options. That way you do not have to import any R.* packages.

In Eclipse, right click on your project go to `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export`. Just make sure that yourprojectname/gen folder is **above** the yourprojectname/src folder.

Comment: Ok!  I will definitely try that.  What exactly will that do?

Comment: As others have already mentioned the R.java file is auto-generated when you do a project build. The Order and Export basically sets the project dependencies. You can read more about it here.

http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737486/what-is-the-use-of-order-and-export-tab-in-java-build-path