# Ordering and Sorting Libraries in Java Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java

In Eclipse, on many occasions i have had issues with the order in which libraries and jars of a project are loaded. i.e. Project -> BuildPath -> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export.

I have the following questions:

1. Are libraries loaded with preference?
2. If two libraries conflict, which one overrides the other?
3. Should the src folder be at the top or should it be the JRE System Library. If so, Why? Is this trivial?

Direct answers or references to reading material would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google and I found a good reference about this "Order and Export" tab, from here on stackoverflow.

[The "Order and Export" tab in "Java Build Path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942628/the-order-and-export-tab-in-java-build-path)

Answer (score 0):

A quick look into that in eclipse and I found that eclipse is only allowing a reordering at library group level, not at library level, as the question was.