# Eclipse order and export tick meaning

Tags: java, eclipse, build, dependencies, export

The question is about eclipse and following options:

[image]

What is the importance of ticking items here? What will happen If we tick/not tick them and when?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The `Order and Export` tab shows the order of libraries which will be included in your project build path.

You can adjust your libraries using the up and down buttons, defining the order according to your project needs.

Here is a similar question: [The "Order and Export" tab in "Java Build Path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942628/the-order-and-export-tab-in-java-build-path)