# Android NoClassDefFoundError for com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

Tags: java, android, json

I have added below 3 jars through eclipse -> Configure build path.

- jackson-annotations-2.4.4.jar
- jackson-core-2.4.4.jar
- jackson-databind-2.4.4.jar

I have the empty constructor in my custom class. I have the required import as well: import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

But when i run the android app, i get error no class def found for ObjectMapper om= new ObjectMapper(); line.

Tried cleaning the project, removing and adding back jars. No luck. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In build path config -> "Order and Export", did you check all of imported jars?

Comment: Thanks a ton, that helped. Why do we need to check in the order&export section?

Comment: No, when you open project properties and go to build path section, there are a tab titled "Order and Export", you should check all of imported jars to revolve your problem.

Comment: You can find more informations here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737486/what-is-the-use-of-order-and-export-tab-in-java-build-path